# Calling a method Recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
  return check(root, 10001, 0);
}

boolean check(Node root, int value1, int value2) {
  if (root != null) {
    if (root.data >= value1 || root.data <= value2) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return check(root.left, root.data, value1) & check(root.right, value2, root.data); //line 13
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Please explain how value1 and value2 are changing in different call ,the given 
 Binary tree is

```
     3
     / \
    5   4
   / \
  1   4
```

Comment: This is a recursive function, no? So even though `value1` and `value2` contain `0` and `10001` the *first* time around, they won't later on.

Comment: What do the values in the binary tree represent? I.E. what do the 3, 5, 1, 4 and other 4 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line `check(root.left,root.data,0) & check(root.right,10001,root.data)` you are calling `check` recursively with different parameters than your expected 0 and 10001. Ignoring the `Node` parameter, the first call uses `root.data` and `0` and the second uses `10001` and `root.data`. Let's consider `check(root.left,root.data,0)`. You are expecting that `value2` would always equal `0`, but this is not the case. You can see that on the same line, you also call `check` as `check(root.right,10001,root.data)`. As you can see, `root.data` is passed as a parameter for `value2`, meaning that if it is not `0`, you have changed the value for `value2` within the call you made. This means the next `check(root.left,root.data,0)` call may have a different value for `value2`, therefore the line `check(root.left,root.data,0)` and `check(root.left,root.data,value2)` are not equal.

If this does not address your question, please edit it to be clearer as it is quite hard to understand what your issue is.

TL;DR - when you use `check(root.right,10001,root.data)` you are changing `value2` so it is no longer `0`. Same applies for `value1`.